# Kendo UI Grid paging issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Kendo UI Grid, I set the Page Size attribute to three - PageSize(3):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Discount>()
    .Name("discountgrid")
    .Columns(c=>
    {
        c.Bound(d => d.Id);
        c.Bound(d => d.Category);
        c.Bound(d => d.Percentage);
        c.Bound(d => d.Merchandise);
        c.Command(cm => { cm.Edit(); cm.Destroy(); });
    })
    .Pageable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(3)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(d => d.Id))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

After adding the first three rows, when I insert the 4th record, the first record disappears (as expected) - but I don't see an option to go to the second page (Page 2) in the grid footer. 
 Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: The code seems ok. How many records do you retrieve? did you check the [demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)?

Comment: @Nilesh I don't know how many records are going to come back - I did check the demos but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: do you see the page navigation bar at the bottom at all? Did you try reloading the grid? Try doing that explicitly! I think you can add a refresh option. You also need to specify the `Read(read=> read.Action("ActionName"))`.

Comment: `.Pageable()` does everything you need. On 'add new' click, grid adds new page if required. Your Edit mode is `GridEditMode.InCell` but action names are bit confusing. Insure that your data is properly saved to db, only then then the grid will be able to refresh on insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the Read action on the DataSource and add the RequestEnd event. You can place your DataSource read method inside this event. The event type parameter on the RequestEnd event such as "update","create","destroy" can then be used to determine which operation is complete and reload the data on the grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Discount>()
.Name("discountgrid")
.Columns(c=>
{
    c.Bound(d => d.Id);
    c.Bound(d => d.Category);
    c.Bound(d => d.Percentage);
    c.Bound(d => d.Merchandise);
    c.Command(cm => { cm.Edit(); cm.Destroy(); });
})
.Pageable()
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(3)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(e => { e.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"); })//onRequestEnd is the javascript fxn
    .Model(model => model.Id(d => d.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read","Grid"))
    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
))


<script type="text/javascript">

function onRequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type === "create" || e.type === "update" || e.type === "destroy") {
        e.sender.read();
    }
}

</script>
```

If you need further information, please read this [link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/kendo-mvc-grid---refresh-after-ajax-row-operation.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing to provide the READ action to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `Read()` action to your grid, and for testing purposes, maybe set `ServerOperation(true)`